# IF statment not checking condition on first run

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm new to programming and I have an app that has a login view on start up and request the user to enter their name which is used throughout out the program. Once they enter their name and log in they are presented with the main menu view. Their name is saved using NSUserdefaults.

The idea is that they will only have to login once (or again if they logout) so they should only see the login view the first time they run the app however once the app is started again it still shows the login screen and also you have to press the login button twice before you are taken to the main menu.

I know that the app is storing the details because it is used thought the app but I cant work out why. Here is my code. If someone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

```
-(IBAction)LogInButton:(id)sender
{
     NSString *tempStr = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"UserName"];

     if(tempStr.length==0) 
     {
          NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
          [prefs setObject:Name.text forKey:@"UserName"];
          [prefs synchronize];

          LogInView *Logview = [[LogInView alloc] initWithNibName:@"LogInView" bundle:nil];
          [self presentModalViewController:Logview animated:YES];
     }
     else 
     {
          MainMenuView *mainview = [[MainMenuView alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainMenuView"      bundle:nil];
          [self presentModalViewController:mainview animated:YES];
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the first time in:

- The login screen shows up
- The user presses login (and this method you're showing gets called)
- The saved value isn't initially set, so this evaluates to true: `if(tempStr.length==0)`
- You save the new value
- You display *another* login screen

But I don't think you're showing all the code. What runs when the app launches?

Comment: Thanks for your reply but Sorry I dont understand what you need. What part of the code do you need to see ie appdelegate.m etc.@steve

Comment: Yeah, I don't know what your filenames are, but whatever code initially decides "do I show the login screen, or do I skip past it and show the main menu"?

Comment: I think maybe this code:}

-(void)LogInSuccess {
 [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 
 MainMenuView *mainview = [[MainMenuView alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainMenuView" bundle:nil];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:(UIViewController *) mainview animated:YES];
 
 [window addSubview:navigationController.view];
 [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}

Answer (score 3):

Judging by your description what you want is

- On `viewDidLoad` check to see if the user is logged in

  - If YES show the `MainMenu`
  - If NO  show the `LogInView`

The code may look like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  [self showCorrectController];
}
```

The show correct controller method could look like this

```
- (void)showCorrectController
{
  UIViewController *viewController = nil;

  if ([self isLoggedIn]) {
    viewController = [[MainMenuView alloc] init];
  } else {
    viewController = [[LogInView alloc] init];
  }

  [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
  [viewController release]; viewController = nil;
}
```

A convenience method is called `isLoggedIn` which looks like this

```
- (BOOL)isLoggedIn
{
  // The double negation just means we get a boolean response
  return !![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"UserName"];
}
```

Now edit your original method to something like this

```
-(IBAction)LogInButton:(id)sender
{
  NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  [prefs setObject:Name.text forKey:@"UserName"];
  [prefs synchronize];
  [self showCorrectController];
}
```

There are quite a few things that could be done to tidy this up a lot but this should be a start to get you going.

A word of caution on your naming of things. The convention is to start method and variable names with lowercased letters. Classes and constants start with uppercase letters.

Comment: Hi Paul. Thanks for the post but can you help. I have followed your instruction but I must be doning something wrong. The app runs but it go the Main Menu without logging in and I also have the following warnings. '...may not respond to correctController' and '...may not respond to isLoggedIn'. Maybe I put something in the wrong file.@Paul.s

Comment: You will need to add the method definitions in the @interface. There are ways to add the definitions so that they do not clutter your public API but to start its fine to just place them into your .h file like this. `- (void)showCorrectController;` and `- (BOOL)isLoggedIn;` add the below where you see this written `-(IBAction)LogInButton:(id)sender`. If it is going straight to `MainMenuController` then this would mean that there is something stored under `@"UserName"`. Check by printing it out to the console `NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"UserName"]);`